# Github Actions: The Job was skipped

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, action, cd

```
jobs:  
  terraform_apply:
    name: "Terraform_apply"
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event.inputs.action == 'Terraform_apply' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
  
terraform_destroy:
    name: "Terraform_destroy"
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event.inputs.action == 'Terraform_destroy' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
```

This is a snippet of my code. I clicked on terraform apply ang got the error message 'The job was skipped'

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is a working example:

Please ensure that you're running this workflow in the master branch

```
name: Terraform Conditional Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      action:
        description: 'Action to perform'
        required: true
        default: 'Terraform_apply'

jobs:  
  terraform_apply:
    name: "Terraform_apply"
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event.inputs.action == 'Terraform_apply' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
  
  terraform_destroy:
    name: "Terraform_destroy"
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event.inputs.action == 'Terraform_destroy' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and give you a feedback